# Asymptotic expansion via Integration by Parts

Tags: integration, asymptotics, self-learning

Chapter 6.3 of Bender & Orszag discusses Integration by Parts for Laplace Integrals
$$ 
I(x) = \int_{a}^{b} f(t) e^{x \phi(t)} \mathrm{d} t \qquad \text{as} \quad x\to \infty 
$$

Using integration by parts one finds
\begin{align}
I(x) = \frac{1}{x} \frac{f(b)}{\phi'(b)} e^{x \phi(b)} - \frac{1}{x} \frac{f(a)}{\phi'(a)} e^{x \phi(a)} - \frac{1}{x} \int_{a}^{b} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}\left[ \frac{f(t)}{\phi'(t)}\right] e^{x \phi(t)} \mathrm{d} t
\end{align}

> Q: Assuming that the integral on the right side exists and $\phi'(t)\neq 0$ on $[a,b]$. How to show that the integral is negligible compared to the boundary terms?

The hint in the book is to divide the integral into subintervals, but I am not sure how this helps (see Problem 6.15).

Comment: The $\phi(t)$ must be negative for the integral to exist. Do we have the condition $a$=0 and $b=\infty$?

Comment: $a$ and $b$ can be finite. Why $\phi$ must be negative, for the integral to exist (for any finite $x$)?

Comment: I see, you are right. The integral does exist no matter $x\to\infty$.